# Reemplazar con RegEx

Tags: regex

Como se podria añadir caracteres delante de una cadena hasta una longitud determinada con **RegEx**.

Por ejemplo, tengo esta cadena de texto y quiero añadirle un **#** delante hasta que la *longitud total* de la cadena sea *12*.

```
cadena ---> ######cadena
```

No encuentro la manera de saber cuantos **#** meterle delante para llegar a la longitud deseada.

```
(.{0,6})

#########$1
```

Comment: Es necesario utilizar un `RegEx`, bueno por si te funciona hacerlo de otra forma te propongo utilizar un `padLeft`. Por ejemplo (en javascript): `'$1'.padStart(12,"#");` esto te devolvera `##########$1`. [mas información](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/padStart) para que revises la compatibilidad de los exploradores (si estas usando javascript). De igual forma en la red hay bastantes ejemplos de padLeft para diferentes lenguajes.

Comment: RegExp no es la solución ideal para este problema, pues facilmente puedes hacer una función que tome la longitud de 12 y la reste a la longitud de la cadena actual para saber cuantos caracteres poner.

Comment: Gracias, ya se que no es la solución ideal pero así esta programado, el regex va dentro de una tabla que después recoge un java que no puedo modificar.

Comment: Podrías aplicar dos expresiones regulares? O solo podrías utilizar una?

Comment: Otra duda: Dónde está almacenado el string que le pasas a la expresión regular?

Comment: @Julio Puedo utilizar varias expresiones regulares, el string es un campo de la base de datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comentas que puedes aplicar varias expresiones regulares, yo lo haría con dos.

La primera se encargará de añadir parrillas `#` suficientes y la segunda eliminará las parrillas innecesarias.

Por ejemplo, dado el string `123456`

La primera expresión regular sería:

Buscar: `^(.*)$`
Remplazar por: `############\1`

Así el texto quedaría: `############123456`

Después al resultado anterior le aplicamos la segunda expresión regular:

Buscar: `^.*?(.{12})$`
Remplazar por: `\1`

Así quedaría: `######123456`

Te dejo una demo de la [primera](https://regex101.com/r/B3kd6u/1/) y la [segunda](https://regex101.com/r/B3kd6u/2/) expresión regular.